# Group By syntax does not seem to be working now

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, viewmodel

I am attempting to select tags from the database. I am using EF Code first 4.2, vbnet and mvc 3. Now early when i first implemented the function I swored it was working properly and did not retreive duplicate tags. Anyways, now it is pulling duplicate tags. Can someone take a look and tell me if there is a flaw in the logic?

```
 Using _rdsqlconn As New RDSQLConn
            Dim tags
            tags = _rdsqlconn.Tags.GroupBy(Function(t) New TagViewModel() With {.TagId = t.TagId, .Tag = t.TagWord}).Select(Function(a) a.Key).ToList()
            ' Dim tags = _rdsqlconn.Tags.Distinct.ToList ' this didnt work

            Return tags
        End Using

Public Class TagViewModel
        Dim _rdsqlconn As RDSQLConn

        Property TagId As Int32
        Property Tag As String
        ReadOnly Property TagCount As Int32
            Get
                Using _rdsqlconn As New RDSQLConn
                    Dim t = _rdsqlconn.Tags.ToList
                    Return t.Count
                End Using
            End Get
        End Property
        ReadOnly Property PostCount As Int32
            Get
                Using _rdsqlconn As New RDSQLConn
                    Dim p = _rdsqlconn.Posts.ToList
                    Return p.Count

                End Using
            End Get
        End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Took out the .TagId portion. Now it does not reutnr duplicate tags